# Receive embedded RTF objects in Outlook 2007(To,Bcc,Cc - Fields)

Tags: email, outlook, rtf, sendmessage, richtext

I have a problem with the Rich Text Fields of Outlook 2007. I try to read the values(email addresses) in the **"To,Bcc,Cc Fields"**. I've read that the problem is known and that you only can read the fields when the mailItem in Outlook is saved.
So, I tried to access the email addresses with a window handler and the SendMessage function. But it only returns :

> {\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1031{\fonttbl{\f0\fswiss\fprq2\fcharset0
>   Tahoma;}} {*\generator Riched20 12.0.6606.1000;}\viewkind4\uc1
>   \pard\f0\fs17{\pict\wmetafile0

So I think Outlook replaces the email address with an embedded object and this object shows the email address. Can anybody help and tell me how to access the object and get the email address?

Answer (score 0):

Use the MailItem.Recipients collection - it will be populated at all times.

Answer (score 0):

I know this, but in Outlook 2007 there is a bug or missing feature. When you delete a (Email-Address)recipient from the to field, the mailItem is not refreshing its recipients collection. It only refreshes when a recipient is added and resolved!

So the only way I see is to read the content of the To-Field is..via SendMessage.

```
    private int EditStreamProc(MemoryStream dwCookie, IntPtr pbBuff, int cb, out int pcb)
    {
        pcb = cb;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[cb];
        Marshal.Copy(pbBuff, buffer, 0, cb);
        dwCookie.Write(buffer, 0, cb);
        return 0;
    }

    private delegate int EditStreamCallback(MemoryStream dwCookie, IntPtr pbBuff, int cb, out int pcb);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct EDITSTREAM
    {
        public MemoryStream dwCookie;
        public int dwError;
        public EditStreamCallback pfnCallback;
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hwnd, uint msg, uint wParam, ref EDITSTREAM lParam);

    private const int WM_USER = 0x0400;
    private const int SF_RTF =3;
    private const int EM_STREAMOUT = WM_USER + 74;


    public string ReadRTFContentInOL2007(IntPtr handle)
    {
        string result = String.Empty;
        using (System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            EDITSTREAM editStream = new EDITSTREAM();
            editStream.pfnCallback = new EditStreamCallback(EditStreamProc);
            editStream.dwCookie = stream;

            SendMessage(handle, EM_STREAMOUT, SF_RTF, ref editStream);

            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                result = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

When the email addresses are resolved then i receive this :

> {\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1031{\fonttbl{\f0\fswiss\fprq2\fcharset0 Tahoma;}} {*\generator Riched20 12.0.6606.1000;}\viewkind4\uc1 \pard\f0\fs17{\pict\wmetafile0

So Outlook replaces the plain text with an object and I need to receive all the Information of the RTF Content! I think somewhere in this content must be the email address. To - Field Class is : RichEdit20WPT

Comment: Did you try to call the Save method after making any changes to the Recipients collection? Does it help?

Comment: @Eugene Astafiev 
Yes, I have tried this and yes it helps. But thats not the clean way to cope with the recipients in my opinion. That leads to a workaround.
So the only way to see changes in the (To;Cc,Bcc)-Rich Text Fields is, i have to add a handler to the fields which checks for updates in the fields, but before that i need to get the content of the fields and that is my problem.

Comment: Outlook caches and doesn't reflect changes made in the UI through the object model. You need to save the item to get the changes visible and ItemChange events fired.

Comment: Okay,thank you.But this is not the way I want do and does not answer my question. I just want to read the content of the Rich Text Field or access all properties of this Richt text field with SendMessage Api.

Comment: What SendMessage API are you talking about? Could you please be more specific?

Comment: Sorry, i mean the SendMessage function. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774304(v=vs.85).aspx
EM_stremout function is the way how i can receive the content of a rich text field. But it doesn't work with resolved email addresses.

Comment: Why do you need to use the SendMessage function from Windows API?

Comment: Because, i want to read the email addresses from the To;Cc,Bcc Fields. That would help me to check if a recipient was deleted by the user in this field and then refresh the mailItem. I already can read the fields, but my problem is, when outlook resolves the addresses in the fields, then i can't read the fields anymore. You see the Addresses in the fields,but there were replaced by an object of outlook, which contains the Address. This is the point,which i am trying to solve. I want to access this object which contains the address and read the address out.